# relative path or absolute path

Tags: php, path, relative-path, absolute-path

in my localhost xampp i have folder inside htdocs , named "google" , and in this folder i have  2 files named is client.php and server3f.php .

so i gave this path in client.php to connect with my server3f.php file and its working in my localhost

```
var host= ws://localhost:12346/google/server3f.php
```

now i uploaded this folder "google" on my remote server inside public_html directory.Now what path should i give ?
 i tried

```
   var host= ws://www.xyz.com:12346/google/server3f.php
```

and

```
var host =ws://www.xyz.com:12346/home/pocket/public_html/google/server3f.php
```

but none of them is working.

i am able to create a page dynamically inside "google" folder  using this path

```
 "/home/pocket/public_html/google/
```

Please help me. What path should i give ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how you are using the 'host' variable. But here are some hints:

If you are producing a link within the same url (which has a document root in ./google), then either will work, e.g.

```
<a href="http://www.xyz.com:12346/google/server3f.php">Visit mygoogle.com</a>

<a href="server3f.php">Visit mygoogle.com</a>
```

if you are producing a link on one server and you want it to connect to another then you need the full address (option 1 above).

if your document root is htdocs, then your local path will be:

```
<a href="./google/server3f.php">Visit mygoogle.com</a>
```

Of course this assumes that you have correctly setup and/or port forwarded port:12346 on your server.